How to select fields from two tables using LINQ
I am trying to select fields from two tables using the Join clause with LINQ, but I am getting this error:

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType213[System.Int32,System.Nullable1[System.Int32],System.String,System.String,,System.Nullable1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable1[System.Int32],System.Nullable1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable1[System.DateTime],System.Nullable1[System.Decimal],System.Nullable1[System.Decimal]]' to type 'ProjectA.Models.Planting'.'

Planting table



CropID
CropName
PlantDate
PlantQty
SiteID




03
Broccoli
22/05/2017
100
PlotA


02
Mango
08/06/2017
20
PlotD


06
Apple
02/07/2018
20
PlotF



Harvest table



Id
CropName
HarvestDate
Weight
CropID




1
Broccoli
05/05/2024
2.00
03


2
Mango
07/05/2024
10.00
02


3
Apple
10/05/2024
4.00
06



The code below is what I have tried;
public class PlantingController : Controller
{
    private readonly dbContext _context;

    public PlantingController(dbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public IActionResult UrlDatasource([FromBody] DataManagerRequest dm)
    {
        IEnumerable DataSource = (from u in _context.Planting join c in _context.Harvest on u.CropID equals c.CropID
        select new { u.CropID, u.CropName, u.PlantDate, u.PlantQty
        c.HarvestDate, c.HarvestQty, c.Weight });           
        return dm.RequiresCounts ? Json(new { result = DataSource}) : Json(DataSource);
    }
    
}

Expected output



CropID
CropName
PlantDate
PlantQty
HarvestDate
Weight




03
Broccoli
22/05/2017
100
05/05/2017
2.0


02
Mango
08/06/2017
20
07/05/2017
10.0


06
Apple
02/07/2018
20
10/05/2017
4.0




The error is quite clear - what about it doesn't make sense?

According to the error, this is related with casting the anonymous type to a specific type.
For example, you could create a viewmodel like below:
public class PlantingHarvestViewModel
{
    public int CropID { get; set; }
    public string CropName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PlantDate { get; set; }
    public int? PlantQty { get; set; }
    public DateTime? HarvestDate { get; set; }
    public decimal? Weight { get; set; }
}

Then modify your Linq:
PlantingHarvestViewModel dataSource = from u in _context.Planting
                 join c in _context.Harvest on u.CropID equals c.CropID
                 select new PlantingHarvestViewModel
                 {
                     CropID = u.CropID,
                     CropName = u.CropName,
                     PlantDate = u.PlantDate,
                     PlantQty = u.PlantQty,
                     HarvestDate = c.HarvestDate,
                     Weight = c.Weight
                 };
                 

